# Whats the difference between socket.io and socket.io-client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Whats the difference between [socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io) and [socket.io-client](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client)?

Some project I'm trying to use is using socket.io-client, but I'm used to using plain old socket.io, and it dons't really lay it out in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference I'm aware of is that with the [socket.io-client](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client) library you can connect your server to another server serving socket.io events.

For example, if my server at `http://localhost` is emitting a `data` event, I can listen on another server like so:

```
var socket = require('socket.io')('http://localhost');
  socket.on('connect', function(){
    socket.on('data', function(data){
      // Do something with data
    });
  });
```

and respond accordingly with the data object passed.